# WPF questionnaire/survey Application

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, layout, navigation

looking to create a kiosk application that should have a start screen with start button.

Once started it will have a few pages of questions. There needs to be an option to go back or start over and a finish button at the end. After finish it goes back to the start screen.

All the information needs to be saved into a SQL Server database.

I'm new to WPF, what's the best approach to navigate between pages etc.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can just use the in-built `NavigationService` to navigate between pages.

Comment: Thank you for your response sa_ddam213. How do I start with a splash screen with just a start button and then have the rest of the pages with navigation buttons? One screen and multiple nested pages? Multiple pages?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Surveymonkey.com? It is a web survey application which can be easily used to display the questions and the data can be exported in various formats. Also, you can display the results online.

I am mentioning this because I am working in market research / data analysis and designing a good questionaire is not a trivial task.

Even if you cannot use Surveymonkey, use it's design as a template - or your customers will not respond to the survey as you would like. Also, run your questions by a couple of people who have an Idea of designing questionaires - the quality of the answers will be drastically improved.

Comment: I have looked at survey monkey and found it too complicated for our simple survey. I also need took use it in a kiosk and not allow the user to do anything but the survey.